# SQLite OR operator

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, where-clause

I need to select the Step Column from a table matching the following conditions:
Union Code 990 and a Set ID of SFMTA or COMMN.
I wrote the following:

```
select Step
from ..
where Union_Code = 990 AND (SetID = 'SFMTA' or 'COMMN');
```

The above query returns no rows, and the solution is the expression:

```
select Step  
from ...  
where Union_code = 990 and (SetID = 'SFMTA' or SetID = 'COMMN')
```

I'm using SQL Lite and am unable to understand why expression for the OR statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OR` is a boolean operator that expects *conditions* as left and right operands:

```
< condition 1 > OR < condition 2>
```

In the first query, the right operand is not an operand, it is a literal string (`'COMMN'`). What happens is that SQLite tries to evaluate the string as a condition: for this, it turns the string to a number (which gives `0`, since the string does not start with a digit), and then evaluate the number as a boolean value (`0` is false). In a nutshell, only the first condition is actually checked:

```
SetID = 'SFMTA' or 'COMMN'
==>     SetID = 'SFMTA' or 0
==>     SetID = 'SFMTA'
```

You need to use a condition as right operand to make your code do what you want - as you found out:

```
SetID = 'SFMTA' or SetID = 'COMMN'
```

Note that this is simpler expressed with operator `IN`, which cheks if the left operand is equal to any of the values given in the list given as right operand:

```
SetID in ('SFMTA', 'COMMN')
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way of the Sql standard is below,

```
select Step  
from ...  
where Union_code = 990 and SetID in ('SFMTA', 'COMMN');
```

`OR` clause should be used only while filtering with different set of columns satisfying either  of the case